# Missing windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, updates

I created a simple windows service with a timer to run in a background time to time. It was just fine having logs and all that stuff.

Today I checked the services and surprise...........my custom windows service is not anymore there . Looking on the event logs, the log is there just with its name.....empty. And also I did some changes on my registry editor to have a custom right click menu, and I noticed that the menu is missing too.

I mention that I run Windows 10 Pro with the latest updates which I think everybody noticed that few days ago.

Is that possible after doing such a major update to Windows to loose your own windows services and any customized environment? If so, how to prevent that happen again in the future?

Comment: Something would have to have stopped and uninstalled your service.

Comment: @RossBush: not necessarily.  Moving from build 1511 to build 1607 involves a reinstallation of the operating system.  The process is *supposed* to copy third-party applications and services into the new build, but it wouldn't be surprising if there were a few kinks.  (There have, I believe, been a number of complaints from end users about third-party software getting uninstalled.)

Comment: What in your mind would be the point of removing user level services. Who would do that and why? Was it a virus do you think?

Comment: @Ross -> I do not have any crappy software/application installed on my machine. The only thing I am aware is that the windows services was installed using installutil.exe per specs on [link] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx [/link] Microsoft Website. Probably, I am not entirely sure if I was using Wix or InstallShield Limited Edition, that thing would not have happen. On the other hand I cannot explain the missing customized right click menu.